# When calling the function the initial state is not changed inside another function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

When I click on an ‘item’ it has to set an initial value for me to do the comparison in another function that has the mousemove event. But when the mouse function move is executed the initial state remains at 0

```js
import React, { createRef, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import style from './styles/drag.module.scss';

function DragItens({ children }: Props) {
  const ref = createRef<HTMLElement>();
  const [move, setMove] = useState(0);
  const [initpositionClick, setInitpositionClick] = useState(0);

  const moveMouse = useCallback((event) => {
    const position1 = event.layerX;
    // setMove(position1 - initpositionClick);
    console.log(initpositionClick);
  }, []);

  function mouseEvent(event: IEvent) {
    const { current } = ref;

    if (event.type === 'mousedown') {
      current?.addEventListener('mousemove', moveMouse);
      setInitpositionClick(event.clientX);
    } else {
      current?.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveMouse);
    }
  }

  return (
    <section
      className={ style.contentcarousel }
      ref={ ref }
      onMouseDown={ mouseEvent }
      role="button"
      tabIndex={ 0 }
    >
      <div
        className={ style.drag }
        style={ { transform: `translate3d(${move}px,0,0)` } }
      >
        <h1>teste1</h1>
        <h1>teste2</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default DragItens;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `initpositionClick` as a dependency for the useEffect, so it will get the newest of it.

```
  const moveMouse = useCallback((event) => {
    const position1 = event.layerX;
    // setMove(position1 - initpositionClick);
    console.log(initpositionClick);
  }, [initpositionClick]);
```

EDIT 1:

- setMove will have the same reference, so it can be passed to outside of the component
- you can store the handler reference, to be able to remove it

```
function getMouseMoveHandler (initpositionClick, setMove) {
  return (event) => {
    const position1 = event.layerX;
    setMove(position1 - initpositionClick);
    console.log(initpositionClick);
  } 
}

function DragItens({ children }: Props) {
  const [move, setMove] = useState(0);
  const mouseMoveHandler = useRef()

  function mouseEvent(event: IEvent) {
    const { current } = ref;

    if (event.type === 'mousedown') {
      current?.addEventListener('mousemove', moveMouse);
      mouseMoveHandler.current = getMouseMoveHandler(event.clientX, setMove)
    } else if (mouseMoveHandler.current !== undefined) {
      current?.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
      mouseMoveHandler.current = undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's just a problem with that you said. 1 that it will return me all the values ​​from the previous click. 2 I can't remove the event after the mouseup event.